# JSON code in large project

Tags: java, uml, structure

I've been programming for a long time as a hobby, but recently discovered the way I structure my projects might be flawed. For this reason, I've come for help.

One of the more recent problems I came across was when I started working on a Java version of a browser game I created. The code setup in that project was as follows.

I had one JSONParser class that I passed on to several other classes such as a Dialog, NPC, Item and Location class. Using the JSONParser, all of the actual parsing would then happen inside those classes.

Taking the Item class as an example (because it's small), I realised that it might be better to seperate the retrieving of the JSON file, the conversion of the data, the parsing of the Item data ánd the actual item object.

[image: A very simplistic version of my old code]

This might be a very non-specific question, but I was wondering how to improve the structure of this code. I have knowledge of abstraction and feel like therein might lie the answer to my problem.

***Just to summarize, there are about 8 classes that all require the JSONParser and all of them have different ways of parsing those files. I want to seperate the parser, parsing and resulting object from eachother.***

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why not just use a Singleton for the JSONParser?

Comment: I'm no expert on singletons, but I've always been told they aren't exactly bad but often considered bad practice. It would improve a part of my old design, but I feel like I can improve the code much more.

Comment: I have no idea how your parser works, but if you have a single one-in-one-out behavior, you can use the singleton. If it works like "init with filename"-"get incrementally data" it won't work, provided that you have different files.